# Problems whit MySQL workbench in ubuntu 20.04 'cannot connect to database server'

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

i installed mysql like this

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`

and i installed mysql workbench, from ubuntu software app.. and when i try to connect to the workbench this happens
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5UBA.png)

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

By default the root user is configured to use `auth_socket` authentication. Have a read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-configure-authentication.html), specifically the section titled `Socket Peer-Credential Authentication`

You must either create a user with the relevant privs and use that to login or change the authentication method for mysql root user.